# How to send an email by Smalltalk application using Gmail / Yahoo / Outlook

Tags: email, gmail, smalltalk, mail-server, yahoo-mail

Is it possible to send an email from Smalltalk using a Gmail account? I have configured my company mail server with Smalltalk to send email, but that's not going to cut it when I distribute the application. Answers with any of using Outlook, Yahoo or Gmail are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should state which Smalltalk you are using since there are different dialects and all have different ways of handling things like e-mail.

In Pharo, check out the class SMTPClient. There are class methods that have example methods showing how to send e-mails.

For VisualWorks, load the parcel NetClients and check out the classes MailMessage and SMTPClient.

Here's an example of code that sends an e-mail in VisualWorks:

```
(Net.SMTPClient host: Net.NetClient netSettings defaultOutgoingHost name)
        user: Net.NetClient netSettings defaultOutgoingHost netUser;
        send: (Net.MailMessage newTextPlain
            subject: 'This is the subject';
            from: 'my-email@gmail.com';
            to: 'your-email@gmail.com';
            text: 'This is the body';
            yourself).
```

Answer (score 0):

For secure mail sending, take a look at `ZdcSecureSMTPClient` in `Zodiac-Extra` on a Pharo 2.0 image.
Class side shows using gmail.